# Getting previous month data not working in sql server

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to get the previous month data according to the datetime in the column dynamically for example
**I have data like this**

[image]

Now I want the records previous than Opendt. The problem is that I am getting the record after Opendt but I am getting empty when I am getting the record before 1 month or 2 month of Opendt

this is the query i am writing

```
select * from dbo.mytable where Valdate between OpenDt and dateadd(Month,-1,OpenDt)
```

the problem is that here -1 and -2 returning empty but when i am adding positive values 1 , 2 and 3 I am getting the records after the OpenDt but not the before Dt Records.

**I need the previous one or two month records before OpenDt**

Comment: Try reversing your BETWEEN:  between dateadd(Month,-1,OpenDt) and OpenDt

Comment: letme check wait

Comment: The lower value for the BETWEEN must always be first.

Comment: [It](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says: "begin_expression AND end_expression ", with a result value of: BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to the value of end_expression.

Comment: @Russ you can make the answer i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reverse the BETWEEN.  The lower value must always be first.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.mytable
WHERE Valdate BETWEEN dateadd(Month,-1,OpenDt) AND OpenDt
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of your Date columns? Are they of any of the date and/or time types described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15?

If not, you may have to change the type for your queries as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 (not recommended) **OR** reload the data with the correct types **OR** create new columns with correct types and update them with date/time values of your date columns. And then use the new columns/correctly typed data in your queries.

Comment: the data types are same